# results of except query change after repeated consecutive runs in redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm running the postgresql query below in aws redshift.  Each time I run this query I'm getting a different result for the number of records that are different on daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query side, using the except operator.  Neither the daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query table or the daily_table.daily_sku_t are being updated during this time.  the daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query table and the product_repeat_sub_query query both have the same record count.  the schema for the daily_table.daily_sku_t is below, the matching fields in the daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query have the same data types.  I've also included some sample records from the tables below.  does anyone have an idea how the results of the except query can come out differently each time this query is run, when the underlying tables aren't changing?

```
daily_table.daily_sku_t schema:

customer_uuid string
boardname_12 string
producttype string
productsubtype string
storeid int
product_id string
dateclosed date
Size string
```

query:

```
with product_repeat_sub_query as
(
        select
            dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.boardname_12,
            case
                when ticketid = first_value(ticketid) over (partition by t.product_id, customer_uuid
            ORDER BY
                dateclosed ASC rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) then 0
                else grossreceipts
            end as product_repeat_gross, datediff(day,
            lag(dateclosed, 1) over (partition by t.boardname_12, customer_uuid, t.product_id
        ORDER BY
            dateclosed ASC ),
            dateclosed) as product_cycle_days
        from
            daily_table.daily_sku_t t )
            
select count(*) from
(
select dateclosed, storeid, boardname_12, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id, product_cycle_days from daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query
except
select dateclosed, storeid, boardname_12, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id, product_cycle_days from product_repeat_sub_query
);
```

-- 36843
-- 36887
-- 36188

data:

daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query

```
dateclosed  storeid boardname_12    producttype productsubtype  size    product_id  product_cycle_days
2021-04-23  427     22RED                       DRUMER          1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    2
2021-04-24  427     22RED                       DRUMER          1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    6
2021-04-26  427     22RED                       DRUMER          1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    8
2021-04-26  427     22RED                       DRUMER          1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    3
2021-05-01  427     22RED                       DRUMER          1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    13
2020-06-18  61      FLAV RX         WINGER      BEVERAGE        100MT   0000265d-6b81-4d79-90cf-xxxxxxxxxxxx    5
2020-06-29
```

product_repeat_subquery

```
dateclosed  storeid boardname_12    producttype productsubtype  size    product_id  product_cycle_days
2021-04-23  427     22RED           DRUMER                      1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    2
2021-04-24  427     22RED           DRUMER                      1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    6
2021-04-26  427     22RED           DRUMER                      1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    8
2021-04-26  427     22RED           DRUMER                      1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    3
2021-05-01  427     22RED           DRUMER                      1T  000011aa-4f03-4f0b-a621-xxxxxxxxxxxx    13
2020-06-18  61      FLAV RX         WINGER      BEVERAGE        100MT   0000265d-6b81-4d79-90cf-xxxxxxxxxxxx    5
2020-06-29
```

update:

```
with product_repeat_sub_query as
    (
            select customer_uuid,
                dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.boardname_12,
                case
                    when ticketid = first_value(ticketid) over (partition by t.product_id, customer_uuid
                ORDER BY
                    dateclosed ASC rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) then 0
                    else grossreceipts
                end as product_repeat_gross, datediff(day,
                lag(dateclosed, 1) over (partition by t.boardname_12, customer_uuid, t.product_id
            ORDER BY
                dateclosed ASC,t.boardname_12, customer_uuid, t.product_id ),
                dateclosed) as product_cycle_days
            from
                daily_table.daily_sku_t t 

where (t.customer_uuid is not null) 
            and (trim(t.customer_uuid) != '')
            and (t.product_id is not null) 
            and (trim(t.product_id) != '')

)
                
    select count(*) from
    (
    select customer_uuid, dateclosed, storeid, boardname_12, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id, product_cycle_days from daily_table.product_repeat_sub_query
    except
    select customer_uuid, dateclosed, storeid, boardname_12, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id, product_cycle_days from product_repeat_sub_query
    );
```

even after adding all the fields from the partition to the order by and filtering our nulls or blanks in the id fields, I'm still getting a different count each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your window functions don't have fully qualified order by clauses.  You have repeated "dateclosed" values within partitions.  This means that Redshift can have different row orders for the lag and first-value functions.  I expect that these "random" ordering differences are causing your changing results.

Comment: thank you very much for getting back to me with this tip!  do you have any suggestions for how to change the query so that the results would be consistent?

Comment: add columns to your order by clause that will ensure exact same ordering every time.   If you don't have any that in combination will do this (you have duplicated rows) then you can add an identity columns that will ensure that this value is different.  The issue is if your query is sensitive to random ordering then what is it suppose to be measuring?  If dateclosed is the same then what row should be returned by lag() to achieve the business result you want?  I cannot help with these questions.

Comment: I tried adding all the fields from the partition to the order by, and filtering out nulls or blanks for the id fields, but I still get a different count of differences each time it runs.  is there something I'm missing?  is this what you meant by qualifying the order by clause?  I've added an update to my original post with my new code.  thank you for the assistance.

Comment: That won't do it.  By definition all the columns in the partition by will be the same within the partition so adding them to the order by does nothing.  Try this "select *, count(*) from daily_table.daily_sku_t group by dateclosed, <all your partition by columns for one of your window functions> having count(*) > 1;".  For these window functions to return consistent results there can only be 1 choice for how to order the rows in the partition.  Now add columns to the group by to get to zero rows where the count > 1.  Then you can add these to the order by clause of the window function.